# Objects in array. Output will get extra symbol

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am playing with array and object. If index value is 2, index value will get two stars symbols, and so on.
I would like to get this result.

**2
******6
****4
***3

```
let arr = [
  {'item': 2},
  {'item': 6},
  {'item': 4},
  {'item': 3},
 
]

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

  let obj = arr[i]

  for(let key in obj) {
    
   let x = '*' + obj[key]
   console.log(x)
  }
}

I am stuck here => 
*2
*6
*4
*6
*3
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to use `let x = "*".repeat(obj[key]) + obj[key]`
This method returnes n times the string (let n be the argument). For example `"*".repeat(5)` returns "*****".

Comment: let x = '*'.repeat(obj[key]) + obj[key]    This is my solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
let arr = [
  {'item': 2},
  {'item': 6},
  {'item': 4},
  {'item': 3}, 
]

arr.forEach(item => {
    console.log("*".repeat(item['item'])+item['item'])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `object.values` in a for/or loop to get the values of each object in the array and `string.repeat` to multiply your '*' by that value:

```
   let arr = [
        {'item': 2},
        {'item': 6},
        {'item': 4},
        {'item': 3},
       
      ]
      
      for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      
        let obj = arr[i]
      
        for (const value of Object.values(obj)) {
            let x = '*'.repeat(value);
            console.log(x + value);
        } 
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

[padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) is another option. You don't need the `obj` variable.

```js
let arr = [
    { 'item': 2 },
    { 'item': 6 },
    { 'item': 4 },
    { 'item': 3 },
]

for (let key of arr) {
    let x = ''.padStart(key.item, '*') + key.item;
    console.log(x)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to do with Array `fill` and `concat` methods.

```js
const arr = [{ item: 2 }, { item: 6 }, { item: 4 }, { item: 3 }];

const stars = (n) => Array(n).fill("*").join("").concat(n);

arr.forEach(({ item }) => console.log(stars(item)));
```